# Flexbox: Even-width items, unless one item overflows its container?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm looking to create a layout of two blocks, side by side, possibly within a flex box. The blocks can contain dynamic text. In most cases, I'd like the blocks to be identically sized. I've found this straightforward by setting flex: 1 on each item. Looks like:
https://codepen.io/benrhere/pen/mdpqjJx

```
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">This is some text</li>
  <li class="flex-item">This is also some text</li>
</ul>

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

[image: Identical width blocks]

However, in the case where one item has contents that overflows its box (say a longer string within), then if the other box has extra space, the overflowing box should take that extra space (but only when it needs it).
See: https://codepen.io/benrhere/pen/KKZyBdj

```
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">This is some text</li>
  <li class="flex-item">This is also some text which overflows</li>
</ul>
```

(Same CSS as above, and almost same HTML but longer string within second 
Currently, the overflow is not visible because the box can't take more than 50%, which makes sense).

Is this possible to achieve this dynamic behavior entirely within CSS? Is Flexbox well suited for this situation?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem.

`flex-basis:100%;` basically said both flex childs go and get 100% width of parent(screen width) but they can only get 50% because both siblings try to get %100.
You can use `flex-basis:50%` that will work too because you want all child containers 50% of screen width but if you go to `flex-basis:35%;` both container will only use 70% of screen.

`white-space:nowrap;` make text in div not wrap.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
  font-size: 62.5%;
}


body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: bisque;
  margin: 0;
  
}

ul,li
{
  margin:0;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}


.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
}


.flex-item {
background-color: tomato;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 3em;
text-align: center;
margin:1rem;
padding: 1rem;
white-space:nowrap;
flex-basis: 100%;
height: 10rem;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <ul class="flex-container">
        <li class="flex-item long-text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</
        </li>
        <li class="flex-item">
         This
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you check please @BenjiFB

Comment: My apologies! I thought that after pasting your solution into a codepen that it yielded the same result as above. But double checking, this solution appears to do exactly what I'm looking for: sharing at exactly 50% until overflow occurs, at which point it will expand. (I've deleted my above comment.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `flex: auto`

e.g.

```css
.flex-container {
  /* We first create a flex layout context */
  display: flex;
  /* Then we define the flow direction 
     and if we allow the items to wrap 
   * Remember this is the same as:
   * flex-direction: row;
   * flex-wrap: wrap;
   *
  
  /* Then we define how is distributed the remaining space */
  justify-content: stretch;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: auto;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  rwidth: 0;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">This is some text and a lot more of it</li>
  <li class="flex-item">This</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think this is close but not exactly what I'm looking for: although this works property to allow each item to expand beyond 50%, it has the downside of expanding before it actually _needs_ to. (I'm presuming 'rwidth' is to disable setting width?) You can see https://codepen.io/benrhere/pen/vYpWMeq shows about a 2/3 , 1/3 split, but https://codepen.io/benrhere/pen/bGaYJYe shows that the same content is actually able to fit in a 50%-sized box. Ideally I'm looking to maintain the 50% split until the box overflow forces it to take more room.